# Как залезть внутрь тега?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Начал изучать парсинг и хочу спарсить цену автопокупки предмета стим(число 1926,57), использую bs4 и requests
Когда получаю весь код страницы, пытаюсь найти по тегу нужный фрагмент, но он оказывается пустым, хотя на сайте его можно раскрыть и посмотреть внутрянку, код и скрины прилагаю

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = requests.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Nightwish%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
price = soup.find("div", id="market_commodity_buyrequests")
print(price)
```

А вот и весь вывод

```
<div id="market_commodity_buyrequests">
                                             
                                        </div>
```

вот html этого куска
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCDE4.jpg
при попытке взять тег span и класс "market_commodity_orders_header_promote", выдаёт либо None,  либо []

Я новичек в парсинге, прошу сильно не ругаться и помочь при возможности)

Comment: В вашем случае, не как, так как сайт динамический. Можете попробывать через селенимум или отлавливайте запросы.

Comment: селениум не хочется использовать, сильно уже замедляет полный код
да и в первой части кода уже использовал его

Comment: Ну тогда анализируйте трафик между браузером и сайтом.

Comment: сложновато для меня)

Comment: "сложновато для меня)" используйте селенимум :)

Comment: А это слишком медленно, ахаха

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за помощь и советы)

Comment: у каждого способа есть свою плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

params = {
    'language': 'russian',
    'currency': '1',
    'item_nameid': '176288589',
}

res = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram', params=params)
print(res.json()['buy_order_summary'])
```

принт

```
Запросов на покупку: <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">2867</span><br>Начальная цена: <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">$62.95</span>
```

Comment: Для одного item_nameid всё хорошо, но когда их порядка 20000, их ещё нужно брать откуда-то)
опять же перегуглил всё что можно и нельзя, нашёл только одну идею, создать базу, в которой будет id каждого предмета, тк они статичные и никогда не меняются